# How to add comments to get stream in react native

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

I want to add a comment section to my react native app similar to instagram's one. I am using a getstream activity feed and have tried importing CommentField from react-native-activity-feed but i get an invariant violation error when i use it. However, i'm not fully convinced the CommentField will get me the type of comment section I want. Does getstream support this or will I need to make my own comment field and save it in a database?

EDIT:

I have this Activity:

```
const CustomActivity = (props) => {
  return (
    <Activity
      {...props}
      Footer={
        <>
<CommentList
            CommentItem={({ comment }) => ( <CommentItem comment={comment} /> )}
            activityId={props.activity.id}
            reactions={props.activity.latest_reactions}
      />
          <Image source={ require('./images/logo.png') } style={{width:98, height:22}}/>
          <LikeButton {...props} />
          <CommentBox
            onSubmit={(text) =>
              props.onAddReaction('comment', CustomActivity, { text: text })
            }
            styles={{ container: { height: 78 } }}
          />

        </>

      }
    />
  );

};
```

Then this gets rendered:

```
<FlatFeed
   feedGroup = "timeline"
   userID = User ID is put here
   Activity={CustomActivity}
   notify/>
```

I currently get this error when I submit a comment: `Errors for fields 'activity_id', 'parent'`

I think it may have something to do with activityId in the CommentList but im not too sure

Comment: can you add the code used for this and perhaps more information about what you want to do?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli I have updated my question with my code and error i get now

Comment: I think the CustomActivity is wrong in: props.onAddReaction('comment', CustomActivity, { text: text }), this should be the activity object, not your custom component.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [CommentBox](https://getstream.github.io/react-native-activity-feed/#!/CommentBox) and [CommentList](https://getstream.github.io/react-native-activity-feed/#!/CommentList) components. We do something like this in our example app:

```
<SinglePost
  activity={activity}
  feedGroup={feedGroup}
  userId={userId}
  Activity={(props) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Activity
        {...props}
      />
      <CommentList
        CommentItem={({ comment }) => ( <CommentItem comment={comment} /> )}
        activityId={props.activity.id}
        reactions={props.activity.latest_reactions} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )}
  Footer={(props) => {
    return (
      <CommentBox
        onSubmit={(text) =>
          props.onAddReaction('comment', activity, { text: text })
        }
        avatarProps={{
          source: (userData) =>
            userData.data.profileImage,
        }}
        styles={{ container: { height: 78 } }}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am slightly confused at where comment and text come from but I have updated my question with my code with the error I currently get

Comment: I have never seen that error before but you also have an error in your code. The CommentList seems to be outside of your return statement. Can you fix that first and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: i have put it inside the return statement now and am getting the same thing. I should add the error message comes in the form of an alert box and the terminal displays no errors. when i click 'ok' on the alert box the app still runs but with a warning saying the same error message and no comments are shown so it hasn't been submitted

Comment: Are you sure the activityId is correct? Can you console.log it?